# How to access class setter in easy way?

Tags: ruby, oop, setter

How it is possible to easy access setter within a same class?

Lets say I have this call:

```
# some_file.rb , create a new object
temperature = Measurement.new 'temperature', 36.6
```

And a model:

```
# Measurements.rb , some model
class Measurement
  attr_accessor :value, :type
  attr_reader :device, :title, :label

  def initialize type, value
    # This one works, but not trigger the setter
    @type = type
    # And this one trigger setter
    self.type = type
  end

  def type= new_type
    # do something very important
  end    
end
```

Does this mean i always need to use `self.var =` instead of `@var =` if I ever want to use setters with this variable without renaming it everywhere in the class? Are there any more difference, and some better way to add a setter?

Comment: Your code is confusing. You wouldn't be able to create the instance before you define the constructor. The order in your code is wrong, or you need to make clear that you are citing two different parts of your code.

Comment: Thank you, it is really two different files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you always do. In Ruby, there is not such thing really as a setter. Just a method that ends in `=`. However, because of syntax ambiguity you must always preface setters with an object and a period, as otherwise Ruby will see an assignment to a local variable instead.

In other words, remember that `@blah` is raw access, and will never trigger a method (not completely true, there are some logging and debugging hock methods, but never-mind).

So just live with `self.blah=` if your setter is that important.